Monitors backlight works when the screen is locked
I have a laptop with two external monitors. When I lock the screen, all three monitors turn off, but right when the last one turns itself off, the laptop's internal display turns on,and after that, the external monitors turn back on too. Then this thing repeats. And then I can see all the displays dim to black color but stay on. How can I just have them all turned off until I get back to the computer and touch the keyboard or mouse?
